# meta tags not showing up in fb-messenger&discord ect... -> when using https

Tags: apache, https, meta-tags

So I recently updated my server from ubuntu **16.04** to **18.04** (full reinstall)

Now I'm having the following issue:

When using **https** no site will embed images or meta tags

https://i.imgur.com/ILFYZ0b
^ same problem with facebook-messenger

Here is my **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin merlijn@melijn.com
    ServerName melijn.com
    ServerAlias www.melijn.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName melijn.com
    ServerAlias www.melijn.com
    ServerAdmin admin@melijn.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-acces.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/merijn/Certs/melijn.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/merijn/Certs/melijn.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

You can visit the sites fine btw:
https://melijn.com
http://melijn.com
I hope there is a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the following:
I had an incomplete certificate and I needed to add a .ca-bundle file in my configuration.
So I added this line:

```
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/file.ca-bundle
```